# Vagrant ansible: pick var fron environment variable

Tags: vagrant

Here my `ansible_local` related `Vagrantfile` code:

```
config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.become = true
    ansible.inventory_path = '/vagrant/provisioning/inventory/hosts.ini'
    ansible.playbook = "/vagrant/provisioning/playbook.yml"
    ansible.limit = 'all'
    ansible.galaxy_role_file = "/vagrant/provisioning/requirements.yml"
    ansible.galaxy_roles_path = "/etc/ansible/roles"
    ansible.galaxy_command = "sudo ansible-galaxy install --role-file=%{role_file} --roles-path=%{roles_path} --force"
end
```

As you can see, `ansible.limit` is `all`.

```
├── ansible.cfg
├── provisioning
│   ├── group_vars
│   │   └── all.yml
│   ├── inventory
│   │   ├── hosts.ini
│   │   └── hosts.yml
│   ├── playbook.yml
│   └── requirements.yml
└── Vagrantfile
```

`all.yml` content is:

```
solr_cores:
mssql_restore_backups: false
```

I need to replace `mssql_restore_backup` default value picking it up from an environment variable.

Is there anyway to pass environment variable value to ansible provisioner?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ansible the variables with mayor precedence are `extra-vars` and you can add them to your Vagrantfile as below

```yaml
ansible.extra_vars = {
  mssql_restore_backup: $MSSQLRESTOREBACKUP
}
```

Documentation:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_common#extra_vars

Comment: Only a tip: Any way to check if environment variable is defined or not? I'd like to do: `another_variable = is_$ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_defined`?